# oci-terraform "remote-exec" script as root user

Tags: terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

We have requirement to execute a script as root. Till now, I'm able to copy my scripts and execute it as opc user but need to make some enhancements to do some operations which required root privilege. 
Appreciate if someone can point me to right resource to achieve this.

Thanks,
Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

The "sudo" command lets you execute commands with superuser privileges as long as your user id is in the sudoers file. The 'opc' user should be in sudoers file, so you can try to use "null_resource" similar to the example in the dns [resource](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci/blob/master/docs/examples/networking/hybrid_dns/dns.tf#L335).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet for how I've used sudo in a remote-exec call:

```hcl
 "provisioner" "remote-exec" {
   "connection" = {
     "host"         = "<Your hostname / ip here>"
     "user"         = "opc"
   }

  "inline" = [
    # Logging for troubleshooting.
    "set -x",

    # Examples of executing pwd & ls using sudo & bash.
    "sudo -s bash -c 'pwd'",
    "sudo -s bash -c 'ls'",
  ]
}}
```